# How do you gracefully handle invalid file uploads / end upload request early?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy to Node.js. I have a route that allows jpg and png image uploads. The route handler checks the magic number in the first few bytes of the request to ensure that the file is the correct format. If the file format is invalid, I want to respond to the client immediately, rather than waste resources handling the remainder of the upload request. Currently, if an invalid upload request is received, I respond immediately with a "Connection: close" header and 415 status.

The problem is that Nginx doesn't seem to like this. The first time I send an invalid request from a client, the client correctly receives the "Connection: close" 415 response from the server, but if I continue to make invalid requests, the vast majority of responses result in a "502 Bad Gateway" from Nginx (i.e. the client never receives the response from the Node.js server). The Nginx error log has "*23 sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream" errors for these "502 Bad Gateway" responses.

I spent some time researching this Nginx error and from what I've found, this is caused because the server is closing the connection before all of the data is sent / read from the client. I still don't understand why this error never occurs on the first invalid request though (only on subsequent invalid upload requests). I've tried setting keepalive_timeout to 0 (to prevent Nginx from overwriting the "Connection: close" header), and also played around with lingering_close to no effect.

The only thing I've tried that works is to read all the data in Node before sending a response / closing the connection. This seems like a complete waste though, as I'm only reading the data for the sake of reading the data, and then immediately discarding it.

Is there a graceful way to handle invalid upload requests like this / a way to configure Nginx to gracefully respond to the client, or is it recommended to read all the data before sending a response, despite the inefficiencies?

Comment: What do you want Nginx to do exactly? Just return 415 to the client instead of 502?

Comment: The 415 response is generated in Node, and is always returned. I need Nginx to send this response back to the client when I cancel the upload early. Nginx doesn't always send this response back to the client though (an error occurs in Nginx, and the 502 Bad Gateway response is sent by Nginx instead). I don't quite understand what's going on though because the 415 response is always correctly sent for the first invalid upload request. It's all subsequent invalid upload requests that cause the 502 error.

Comment: and just to clarify, it's all subsequent upload requests sent by that particular client that cause the 502 error, not different clients (i.e. the first time a client sends an invalid upload, the 415 response is correctly returned, and if that same client then sends another invalid upload, then the Nginx "23 sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe)" error occurs, and the 502 Bad Gateway response is sent instead of the 415).

Comment: On the second invalid request does the Node server still generate a 415 which Nginx then ignores? Have you got a proxy_intercept_errors directive in your config?

Comment: Yeah, the Node server always generates the 415 response. It just doesn't get passed through Nginx to the client on the second invalid request onward (i.e. Nginx is essentially overwriting the Node 415 response with its own 502 Bad Gateway response, which I assume results from the Broken Pipe error I mentioned). Also, proxy_intercept_errors is off.

Comment: How is your node server defined in your nginx conf files? Do you have a location in a server block with a `proxy_pass` directive which proxies directly to the node server ip:port or do you proxy to an upstream block you have defined for the node server?

Comment: I have a location block within a server block, with the proxy_pass directive proxying directly to the node server IP:port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179768/discussion-between-miknik-and-froglegs).